# Fn Key with non-media keys

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to bind the Fn key of a laptop keyboard with non-media buttons? I tried it in the "Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts" but it only recognizes the Fn + media key as an VOLUME-UP for example. 
Is it possible or is it just the keyboard sending a "viritual key" to the OS and the OS not knowing if Fn is actually pressed?